# RecordRTC video upload AmazonS3 Timeout error

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, html5-video, webrtc, video-capture

I am currently developing a component that allows you to make webcam videos and upload them directly to amazon s3. For that purpose I user RecordRTC library and Amazon S3 storage. I have discovered a strange issue, and I am not sure whether it has to do with RecordRTC blobs or with amazon configuration. When the file size is over 1MB, the Amazon server hangs and after 20 seconds returns a timeout error. Could anyone help me figure this out? Here is my code for the recorder component (p() is the same as console.log()):

```
navigator.record_function = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia);
        if (navigator.record_function) {
            navigator.record_function(videoObj, function (stream) {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
                $("#stop_recording").click(function () {
                    stream.stop();
                });

                // init recorders
                audio_recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {type: "audio", bufferSize: 16384});
                video_recorder = RecordRTC(stream, videoOptions);

            }, errBack);
        }

$("#start_recording").click(function () {
        // record the audio and video
        video_recorder.startRecording();
        audio_recorder.startRecording();
    });
```

And for the uploader component:

```
// Populate the Post paramters.
  fd.append('key', "users/" + Main.current_user.id + "/test.webm");
  fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', msg.access_key_id);
  fd.append('acl', 'private');
  fd.append('policy', msg.policy);
  fd.append('signature', msg.signature);
  fd.append('Content-Type', '$Content-Type');
  fd.append('x-amz-server-side-encryption', 'AES256');
  fd.append('success_action_status', '201');
  fd.append('name', 'test.webm');
  fd.append('Filename', 'test.webm');
  fd.append("file", file);
  xhr.open('POST', 'https://' + msg.bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com', true);
  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
    p(e);
  }, false);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    p(xhr.readyState);
  };

  xhr.send(fd);

    $("#stop_recording").click(function () {

        // stop recorders
        audio_recorder.stopRecording(function () {
                    var audio_blob = audio_recorder.getBlob();
                    p(audio_blob);
                    // VideoUploader.upload_user_audio(audio_blob);
                }
        );
        video_recorder.stopRecording(function () {
            var video_blob = video_recorder.getBlob();
            p(video_blob);
            VideoUploader.upload_user_video(video_blob);
        });
    });
```

The error message on timeout is:

```
Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
```

I appreciate any help I can get, I am really lost here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/rjmackay/recordly.io or this: https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client You can even use "bufferSize:0" which will let Chrome decide audio-buffer size (e.g. 2048). Smaller bufferSize will generate smaller WAV. You can ven use "leftChannel:true" to record only left (mono) channel. It'll reduce half/size. You can even try MediaStreamRecorder.js to get intervals based blobs: https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder

Comment: Thanks for the input. In the meantime I figured out that the problem is not related to S3, since it persists even if I try uploading a file greater than 1MB to a local server. The browser I tested on is firefox. I will try using media stream recorder to see if it behaves differently.

Comment: This is an interesting phenomenon. I tried using MediaStreamRecorder, the same error persists. If the recording is greater than 1MB, the the upload hangs. What is interesting is that the error does not happen on Chrome! Only Firefox appears to have this issue. Could there be some kind of a buffer issue specific to Firefox or certain other browsers?

Comment: You may need to try jQuery uploader instead of using XHR directly.

Comment: From my observations, S3 is not always returning response, sometimes it hangs and returns just 400. The solution you provided fixes the problem - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a pretty... strange solution for this issue. It appears the problem comes from the way RecordRTC saves the blob object, which makes it impossible to upload in Firefox 35 on Mac. I could not find the code in RecordRTC that causes the problem, the Blob seems to be generated correctly, but the workaround that worked for me was encoding the Blob again into a new Blob via Filereader.

```
video_recorder.stopRecording(function () {
            var video_blob = video_recorder.getBlob();
            var arrayBuffer;
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function (ex) {
                arrayBuffer = this.result;
                video_blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: "video/webm"});
                VideoUploader.upload_user_video(video_blob)
            };
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(video_blob);
        });
```

As for why that happens, I have no idea, but other projects that use the same technology are affected as well http://videobooth.herokuapp.com/ (the same exact problem in the same exact browser, upload hangs). Maybe this information could be useful for people working on RecordRTC, as I think this workaround could be made into a patch.

Solution is tested on Mac Firefox 35 and Mac Chrome 40.

Comment: You've got no idea how long it took me to find that you had exactly the same issue. For those of looking for promise-based async/await result:
const fileReader = new FileReader();
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fileReader.onerror = () => {
            fileReader.abort();
            reject(new Error('Problem parsing input file.'));
          };

          fileReader.onload = (e) => {
            video = new Blob([e.target.result], { type: 'video/webm' });
            resolve();
          };
          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(video);